# how to declare a global variable in Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a C# Class Library for my Web Application and I'm stuck with a problem I know its so silly but I cant figure out any solution.

I want to create a string variable containing my database connection string and I've to call that variable in more than one classes.

I cant find any suitable ways for it.

In my previous application I use `Web.config` for solving these kind of problems by creating a new key in App setting, However in a class library project **there is no** web.Config file so is there any way to initialize globally

Comment: you can use the app.config  file . Even when you will include the C# project to web application in can read from the web.config

Comment: Don't club your question into one giant wall of text. It gets hard to read.

Comment: Just declare a public static field in your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you put the connection string in the .config of the startup project, not the class library project.

So, just put it in Web.config (or App.config) and it will be available from the class library as well.

Comment: It's also a good idea to create a class, perhaps in your class library project, which provides static and strongly typed references to your config settings.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you should still use a configuration file and add a connection string as you would normally in your web application and in your class library access it as per normal. The class library runs under the web application so will have access to its **web.config**.

If you include your class library in Project A and Project B it will use whichever config file is in that project. This includes unit tests etc.

Answer (score 0):

This "global variable" already exists: It's the ConfigurationManager and, in your case, the ConnectionStrings collection.

You just have to define a unique connection string name to retrieve the connection string from the executable's .config file.